# MVC - Pass from Jquery to View Information

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a value in Jquery. I need to apply that value to a view which has a model. 
For example, I need to do assign it to the :

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.program.programid)
```

the variable that I am trying to store in `model.program.programid` is called `prog`.

I tried:

```
    $('#program_programid').val(prog);
```

but does not seem to assign it the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is a textbox, `val()` sets its value:

```
$('#program_programid').val(prog);
```

If not, then use `text()`:

```
$('#program_programid').text(prog);
```

Comment: I tried both ways but still does not seem to work. Note that model => model.program.programid is from the program table with the field being programid from the viewmodel